# In a Multi-Module maven project, is it possible to have module B depend on a Plugin provided by Module A

Tags: maven

I am trying to build a project containing multiple modules, one of which is a maven plugin which we use to generate sources further down the tree as such:

1. Module A: generator-plugin
2. Module B: uses generator-plugin

But when I try to build the parent project (doing a mvn clean deploy) during the clean phase, it tries to resolve the generator-plugin, which is obviously before it's built it.

Is there a way for this to be done without separating out the modules and building it first manually?

Comment: Is Module A your plugin? Or does it only have the dependency for it?

Comment: Module A is the plugin itself.

Answer (score 1):

With Maven, I would suggest doing the most straightforward thing which would work and I think you know what that is--just make these two things separate Maven projects.